# Why my code vulnerable to xss attack?

Tags: php, html, xss

I have php code like this

```
<?php
    $input_from_user = "w' onclick = 'alert(document.cookie);'";
    $i_am_barcelona_fan = htmlentities($input_from_user);
?>
<input type = 'text' name = 'messi_fan' value ='<?php echo $i_am_barcelona_fan;?>' />
```

I am using `htmlentities` to protect from XSS attack, but still I am vulnerable to the above string.
Why is my code vulnerable to XSS attack? How can I protect from my code from it?

Comment: `htmlentities()` is not the be-all-end-all solution against XSS

Comment: It's because you're a Barcelona fan. Lots of bitter people.

Comment: A good article for the prevention of xss.. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-secxss/ hope it helps..

Comment: any problem with my question? someone voted for closing my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not telling PHP to escape quotes as well, and you should use `htmlspecialchars()` instead:

```
<input type = 'text' name = 'messi_fan' value ='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($input_from_user, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>' />
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/bphh5p)

Answer (score 2):

Never ever (ever) trust foreign input introduced to your PHP code. Always sanitize and validate foreign input before using it in code. The filter_var and filter_input functions can sanitize text and validate text formats (e.g. email addresses).

Foreign input can be anything: $_GET and $_POST form input data, some values in the $_SERVER superglobal, and the HTTP request body via fopen('php://input', 'r'). Remember, foreign input is not limited to form data submitted by the user. Uploaded and downloaded files, session values, cookie data, and data from third-party web services are foreign input, too.

While foreign data can be stored, combined, and accessed later, it is still foreign input. Every time you process, output, concatenate, or include data in your code, ask yourself if the data is filtered properly and can it be trusted.

Data may be filtered differently based on its purpose. For example, when unfiltered foreign input is passed into HTML page output, it can execute HTML and JavaScript on your site! This is known as Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) and can be a very dangerous attack. One way to avoid XSS is to sanitize all user-generated data before outputting it to your page by removing HTML tags with the strip_tags function or escaping characters with special meaning into their respective HTML entities with the htmlentities or htmlspecialchars functions.

Another example is passing options to be executed on the command line. This can be extremely dangerous (and is usually a bad idea), but you can use the built-in escapeshellarg function to sanitize the executed command’s arguments.

One last example is accepting foreign input to determine a file to load from the filesystem. This can be exploited by changing the filename to a file path. You need to remove ”/”, “../”, null bytes, or other characters from the file path so it can’t load hidden, non-public, or sensitive files.

Learn about data filtering (http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php)

Learn about filter_var (http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)

Comment: What's more important than sanitisation is proper escaping though. The string in this could be considered "sane" under certain circumstances.

Comment: Sanitization removes (or escapes) illegal or unsafe characters from foreign input.

Sometimes it is required to allow some safe HTML tags in the input when including it in the HTML page. This is very hard to do and many avoid it by using other more restricted formatting like Markdown or BBCode, although whitelisting libraries like HTML Purifier exists for this reason.
Exemples here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php

Comment: It still depends on the context which characters are indeed illegal or unsafe; whereas escaping can be applied on the original value as and when it "leaves" the system. Allowing a safe subset of HTML is not part of the question.