# Htmlentities incress the string character

Tags: php

I have a input text box `maxlength 20` and use jquery auto count how many words left.

I have also use `strlen` to check before it insert into DB
`varchar(20)`(if too many characters, wont insert into DB), and htmlentities to prevent xss

Here is the problem, htmlentities will increase characters. So if auto count shows 17 but it actually over than 17 characters because htmlentities.

I don't want data truncate, any suggestion?

Comment: put the validation to enter only alpha numeric characters

Comment: Wait. Do you use `htmlentities` before inserting in db?

Comment: i did use it before db, should i only use it for out put?

Comment: To answer that, read http://kunststube.net/escapism.

Comment: htmlentities will not protect you from XSS. see this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15802624/why-my-code-vulnerable-to-xss-attack

Comment: @messi The question you link to and what you said does not match in any way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Never* encode for display before storage, only before display.